# What exactly is we-ve-just-wanted-to-be-sure-you-are-paying-attention test?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-audits

So today one of my answers was edited and the edit itself was quite tricky - it was looking legit though actually was invalidating my answer, so I've declined it.

Then I've got this message:
[image]

My question is following - what this testing is about (how massive it is, what exactly are you trying to achieve, who is in the test group etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there was a consecutive post you had to review after you reviewed your own post, and that review happened to be an review audit.

Those audits make sure you pay attention when you review other posts from the review queue. More about suggested edits and review queues in the FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/245360).

Comment: (I think you as a moderator should have know this, didn't you?)

Comment: either I've missed a letter or - even worse - I have no idea that is the approved way of getting this kind of news.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's slightly unfair to expect shabunc to know this; he moderates a site that doesn't have review audits.

Comment: Okay. That is true. @art. Didn't realize that.